# Making Integrate find an integral involving logarithms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I need to simplify the following integrand to make it work with `Integrate`, I've tried to make a  substitution with `u = x ln(x)`  but I have `1 + ln(x)` remaining multiplying `Sqrt[ 1 + 1/u^2] du`.

[image]

Since `Simplify` doesnt work either, can anyone show me a simplified version?

Answer (score 6):

**I.**

We will demonstrate that the indefinite integral for $\;x>1\;$ is$$\int (1+\ln(x))\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2 \ln(x)^2}} d x=\ln\bigg(\frac{x \ln(x)}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2\ln(x)^2}}\bigg)+\sqrt{1+x^2\ln(x)^2}\\=-csch^{-1}(x \ln(x))+\sqrt{1+x^2 \ln(x)^2}$$
**II.**

Let's take a closer look at the main issue.
This  input remains unevaluated

```
Integrate[(1 + Log[x]) Sqrt[1 + 1/(x^2 Log[x]^2)], x]
```

neither  indefinte nor with a specified range of integration e.g. `{x, 2, 3}`.

**III.**

However if we change the variable $x\to u= x \ln(x)$ we should take into account also the appropriate measure of integration and so $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2 \ln(x)^2}} \to \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{u^2}}$ as well as $(1+\ln(x)) d x \to d u$ since $\frac{d u}{d x}=1+\ln(x)$

Thus we have $$\int (1+\ln(x))\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2 \ln(x)^2}} d x \to \int \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{u^2}} d u$$  as well as in a definite form
$$\int_{a}^{b} (1+\ln(x))\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2 \ln(x)^2}} d x=\int_{a \ln(a)}^{b \ln(b)} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{u^2}} d u $$
**IV.**

In the following definition we have had to apply slightly **superfluous assumptions** (e.g. putting `1 < a < b`  we get the result in terms of `ConditionalExpression` with a condition implied by the assumption)

```
int[a_, b_] = 
  Assuming[ 1 < a < b && a Log[a] < b Log[b], 
            FullSimplify[ Integrate[ Sqrt[1 + 1/u^2], 
                                     { u, a Log[a], b Log[b]}]]];
TraditionalForm @ int[a, b]
```

[image]

and it is numerically equal to the numeric integral, e.g.

```
{N[int[2,3]], N[int[2,3]]==NIntegrate[(1 + Log[x]) Sqrt[1 + 1/(x^2 Log[x]^2)], {x, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> 2.106
> ```

**V.**

One has to pay attention that this integral $\int_{1}^{b} (1+\ln(x))\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2 \ln(x)^2}} d x$ is divergent as well as $\int_{a}^{1} \dots$ for $\;0<a<1<b$, nevertheless the same substitution works well also for limits of integration in the range $ 0 < a < b < 1$. Then instead of defining another integral we can use `int` with  reversed limits of integration or simply changing the sign e.g. for $\;\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \dots$ instead of `int[1/3, 1/2]` we calculate `int[1/2, 1/3]`.

**VI.**

Here we demonstrate that for $\;1<x$ $$-\ln\bigg(\frac{x \ln(x)}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2\ln(x)^2}}\bigg)=csch^{-1}(x \ln(x))$$

Acting on the both sides of this equation with hyperbolic cosecant we can see that the above is equivalent to

```
FullSimplify[ x Log[x] == Csch[-Log[(x Log[x])/(1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2 Log[x]^2])]], 
              x > 1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: +1, very nice substitution there!

Comment: Can you automate the substitution?

Comment: @yarchik As you can see I have had to use specific assumptions which are superfluous and it couldn't be anticipated. In `Integrate`  there are many similar issues and so automating such substitutions is possible in specific cases but it is not what could be made in advance, i.e. it doesn't provide a general useful solution.

Comment: But assumptions are for the integral, not the substitution.

Answer (score 3):

`Rubi 4.15.2` implemented in `Mathematica 12.0` cracks it:

```
Int[(1 + Log[x]) Sqrt[1 + 1/(x^2 Log[x]^2)], x]
```

> $$x \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 \log ^2(x)}+1} \log (x)-\text{csch}^{-1}(x \log (x)) $$

The result as an input form is

> ```
> -ArcCsch[x Log[x]] + x Sqrt[1 + 1/(x^2 Log[x]^2)] Log[x]
> ```

Comment: Rubi makes the same change as @Artes.

Comment: Its derivative is $$\frac{\log (x)+1}{x^2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 \log ^2(x)}+1} \log ^2(x)}+\log (x) \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 \log ^2(x)}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 \log ^2(x)}+1}+\frac{x \log (x) \left(-\frac{2}{x^3 \log ^3(x)}-\frac{2}{x^3 \log ^2(x)}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 \log ^2(x)}+1}} $$ and the Simplify command produces $$ \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 \log ^2(x)}+1} (\log (x)+1).$$ Verify your check.

Comment: @Artes:$\text{csch}^{-1}$ is ArcCsch.

Comment: Ok, formerly I lost a minus sign before `ArcCsch`, +1.

Comment: Mathematica **12.1** can't find  :(

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk even using the improved `Asymptotics`?

Comment: @CATrevillian. You can try the improved `Asymptotics` in WolframCloud https://develop.wolframcloud.com

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thanks! Can you clarify if the version there is what is in implemented in the current 12.1 rc?

Comment: @CATrevillian. I don't know the answer to your question.